# Why Does Google API Not Connect and Times Out

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, raspberry-pi3, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use the API Key and it does take the picture on the Raspi but then gets stuck trying to send it to the Drive and I am unsure why.

Note: I took out the key and ID for privacy but I do actually have the proper info there

```
import os
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

API_KEY = "key"
FOLDER_ID = "ID"

def authenticate_drive():
    service = build('drive', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)
    return service

def take_picture(service):
    now = datetime.now()
    date_string = now.strftime("%m_%d_%y_%H%M")
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'camera', 'pics_new', 'pic%s.jpg' % date_string)
    
    with PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
        camera.framerate = 20

        sleep(3)
        camera.capture(file_path)
        prPeriwinkle("TAKE PICTURE", datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        
        prNeonPink("Sending to Drive", datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        
        # Upload the picture to Google Drive
        file_metadata = {'name': os.path.basename(file_path), 'parents': [FOLDER_ID]}
        media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='image/jpeg')
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

        print("Uploaded to Google Drive")

def main():
    service = authenticate_drive()
    take_picture(service)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After a while it out puts this:
sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
socket.timeout: timed out

I have been trying to solve this for some time and cannot figure it out

I tried using the API Key from Google API to upload pictures to the Drive but it gets stuck trying to send the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Api keys only give you access to public data.

You can't upload with an API key it requires private account to a user account use oauth2

## Oauth2

```
def build_service(credentials, scope, user_token):
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists(user_token):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(user_token, scope)

    # If there are no (valid) user credentials available, prompt the user to log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                credentials, scope)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(user_token, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    try:
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - any errors returned.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Comment: The thing with oauth2 is after I enter the verification code it never goes through and uploads. Another issue is the code runs for weeks but the verification only lasts a day and that causes issues

Comment: Not sure what a verification code is.  Oauth2 is in sevral steps.  1. URL request authorization of the user 2. returns an authorization code 3. you exchange the authorization code for an access token 4.  you send Access token to the api.   What you have is not enough to request authorization of the user.

Comment: So right now it 1. Creates URL to authorize 2. Creates authorization code 3. I paste it in the terminal 4. It takes a long time to accept the code but it does. 5. Take picture and gets stuck trying to upload it

There was a time a different version of the code using OAuth2 would successfully take the access token and upload the pictures but lately it has not